# How do I create a resolver with multiple requests dependent on data from a prior request?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-resolver

I have a component which retrieves its business object from a single HTTP request, and then has several subsequent requests to populate drop-down lists. The arguments in those subsequent requests consist of data from the business object, so those requests can not begin until the first one completes.

Given an example resolver `PersonResolver`, this is the flow I want to achieve:

1. Call `this.personService.getPersonData()`. Returns type `Observable<PersonModel>`.
2. Use the returned `PersonModel` instance, which we'll call `personData`, to call `this.personService.getAdditionalData1(personData.foo)` and `this.personService.getAdditionalData2(personData.bar)`. Both return type `any[]`.
3. Return type `Observable<PersonModel, any[], any[]>` from the `resolve` method.

I would like to implement this into the component's resolver, but I am having a tough time wrapping my head around the correct usage of RxJS I need for the job.

Here's what I've got so far. I got stuck pretty quick.

```ts
constructor(private personService: PersonService) { }

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<PersonModel, any[], any[]> | Observable<Observable<PersonModel, any[], any[]>> | Promise<Observable<PersonModel, any[], any[]>> {
  this.personService.getPersonData().subscribe(personData => {
      // what to put in here?
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to use `mergeMap` in order to pass the model `PersonModel` from first call. Then you need to use `zip` to get all of the result together in one array.

```js
    this.personService.getPersonData.pipe(
      mergeMap(
        personData => zip(
          of(personData),
          of(getAdditionalData1(personData.foo)),
          of(getAdditionalData2(personData.bar))
        )
      )
    ).subscribe(allData => {
      // here you will have all of the data placed in 'allData' param
    });
```

See this simple [StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-54133290) to see this in action

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using `forkJoin` instead of `zip` just because we're using it in other resolvers, but it seems to have the same end result.

Comment: `forkJoin` is currently deprecated, so use `zip`.

Comment: @EugeneP. the " forkJoin " is not deprecated, it's just the method that has changed ... Instead of using :  forkJoin(Observable1(), Observable 2()) <===> we pass the observables into an array ==>  forkJoin([Observable1(), Observable 2()]).

Answer (score 1):

> Try something like this...

Note: [READ THIS](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs)

```
constructor(private personService: PersonService) { }

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<PersonModel, any[], any[]> | Observable<Observable<PersonModel, any[], any[]>> | Promise<Observable<PersonModel, any[], any[]>> {
  return this.personService.getPersonData().pipe(
    mergeMap(personData => this.personService.getAdditionalData1(personData.foo)),
    mergeMap(this.personService.getAdditionalData2(personData.bar)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another version

```
this.personService
  .getPersonData()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(personData =>
      merge(
        this.personService.getAdditionalData1(personData.foo),
        this.personService.getAdditionalData2(personData.bar)
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(
    r => console.log('Response', r),
    e => console.log(e),
    () => console.log('Done')
  );
```